# ¿Puedo llenar variables de js con variables de php con fetch data?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

Estoy terminando de realizar un proyecto, el cual consiste en un **escáner qr**. Hasta ahora he logrado casi todo.

Explico un poco: esos **qr** son generados por mi sistema y encriptados. Cuando yo lo escaneo me desencripta el contenido si es **qr** generado por el sistema, y esa información es enviada con **js** por `fetch` con método `post` a un archivo **php** donde realizo una consulta a mi **bd** para obtener unos datos, los cuales son *almacenados en variables*.

Posteriormente del lado del escáner me trae el `data` del archivo **php** y me hace las comparaciones donde, si el **qr** pertenece al sistema *me muestra un mensaje de aceptación* y si no es un **qr** generado por el sistema *envía un mensaje de error*.

Mi cuestión es ¿cómo puedo hacer para que me genere una tabla en **html** con los datos de las variables de **php**?. Es decir ¿cómo traer en el `data` esas *variables* o el *contenido de las mismas* de forma correcta y pasarlas a variables de **js** para imprimirlas en una tabla del **html**?

Espero darme a entender, dejo mi código para que le den un vistazo.

HTML y código del escáner:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Tutores COLMEX</title>
    <link href="images/icons/favicon.ico" rel="icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="template/readqr/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table-align-middle">
            <tbody>
              <td>
                <div class="video-container">
                  <video id="preview"></video>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="video-container" id="respuesta">
                </div>
              </td>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <table class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">First</th>
                <th scope="col">Last</th>
                <th scope="col">Handle</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="contenido">
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>Mark</td>
                <td>Otto</td>
                <td>@mdo</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
  let scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({
    video: document.getElementById('preview')
  });

  Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(cameras => {
    scanner.camera = cameras[cameras.length - 1];
    scanner.start();
  }).catch(e => console.error(e));

  scanner.addListener('scan', content => {
    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("qr", content);
    fetch('template/modulos/qrcheck.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: datos
      })
      //.then( res => res.json())
      .then(res => res.text())
      //.then (text => console.log(text))
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        tabla(data)
        if (data === '"error"') {
          respuesta.innerHTML = `
<br>
<div class="alerta" style="text-align: center; background-color: blue; color: white;">
<br>
<h1>¡Este QR no pertenece a ninguno de los tutores del alumno!<h1>
<br>
</div> `
        } else {
          if (data.indexOf('aprobado')) {
            respuesta.innerHTML = `
<br>
<div class="alerta" style="text-align: center; background-color: green; color: white;">
<br>
<h1>¡Este QR pertenece a los tutores del alumno!<h1>
<br>
</div> `
          }
        }
      })
    var nombre = ('<?php include ("template/modulos/qrcheck.php") echo $nombre?>')

    function tabla(data) {
      contenido.innerHTML = ''
      for (let valor of data) {
        console.log(nombre)
      }
    }
    scanner.start();
  });
});

</script>    
    </section>
    <script src="template/readqr/script.js"></script>
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Archivo PHP

```php
<?php
include '../global/cn.php';
include 'hash.php';

$qr= $_POST['qr'];
$matricula = protect::desencrypt($qr);

if ($matricula != '') {
    $consulta = $mysqli->prepare ("SELECT * FROM alm a INNER JOIN papas b on a.matricula = 
    b.matricula WHERE b.matricula = '$matricula'");
    $consulta->execute();
    $resultado = $consulta->get_result();
    $row = $resultado-> fetch_assoc();

    $nombre= $row['nombre'];
    $matricula= $row['matricula'];
    $grado= $row['grado'];
    $grupo= $row['grupo'];
    $nivel= $row['nivel'];
    $tutor1= $row['nombre1'];
    $tutor2= $row['nombre2'];
    $tutor3= $row['nombre3'];
    $foto= $row['foto'];
    $foto1= $row['foto1'];
    $foto2= $row['foto2'];
    $foto3= $row['foto3'];
    $acceso = "aprobado";
} else {
    echo json_encode('error');
}
?>
```

Cualquier comentario es de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Con todas las variables así por separado no puedes. Mételas todas juntas en un objeto (en su defecto, un array si no usas POO). Luego es tan simple como `return $nombreDeTuObjeto` y eso es lo que tendrás en JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lees la documentación, verás que [`fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) ya te crea un arreglo asociativo usando como clave cada columna de la tabla (si no te gustan los nombres de las columnas o quieres otros, entonces usa esos que quieres como alias en la consulta SQL y problema resuelto).

Siguiendo la idea anterior, entonces puedes devolver un JSON con `$row` simplemente, sin necesidad de crear variables para cada valor.

Luego, en la parte del error, puedes crear igualmente un array con una clave `error`.

Finalmente, en la petición `fetch`  de Javascript conviene que indiques un `json()` en vez de un `text()`, porque te permite transportar los datos más organizados (si por algún motivo prefieres usar `text()` entonces cambia todo en el servidor, creando una cadena con los datos obtenidos.

Así debería funcionar:

### En PHP cambiar lo siguiente:

```
if ($matricula != '') {
    $consulta = $mysqli->prepare ("SELECT * FROM alm a INNER JOIN papas b on a.matricula = 
    b.matricula WHERE b.matricula = '$matricula'");
    $consulta->execute();
    $resultado = $consulta->get_result();
    $row = $resultado-> fetch_assoc();
    echo json_encode($row);

} else {
    echo json_encode(array('error'=>'No hay datos'));
}
```

### En Javascript:

```
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    if (data.error) {
        /*Llenar tu plantilla de error*/
        console.log(data.error);
    } else {
        /*Llenar tu plantilla con los datos*/
        console.log(data);
        /*
            Tampoco veo que uses los datos 
            que traes del servidor
            Si no vas a usar datos, no transportes datos
        */
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Buen día compañero, gracias por compartir tu perspectiva, realize algunos cambios de los que mencionas, mi duda es como puedo llenar con ese echo json_encode($row); una tabla en html con json, no logro entender como imprimir ese array automáticamente

Comment: @GustavoCuevasPalafox hay varias formas de leer un JSON en Javascript. ¿Has investigado intentado alguna? Indica lo que has intentado y podremos ayudarte en ese sentido. Ni siquiera sabemos cómo se llaman las columnas de tu tabla para saber cómo leer el JSON.